# How to get the nth word from a string if there are more spaces between the words?

Tags: c#, string, if-statement

I am trying to print out the xth word from a sentence like this:

```
string phrase = Console.ReadLine();
int wordIndex = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
string currentWord = "";
int currentWordIndex = 1;

for (int i = 0;  i < phrase.Length; i++)
{
if (phrase[i] != ' ')
    currentWord += phrase[i];

if (phrase[i] == ' ' || i == phrase.Length - 1)
{
    if (wordIndex == currentWordIndex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(currentWord);
        break;
    }

    currentWord = "";

    if (i != phrase.Length - 1)
        currentWordIndex++;
 }

}

if (wordIndex > currentWordIndex)
Console.WriteLine("N/A");
```

I want it to work even if there are more spaces between words. Any help, please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
string[] splited = phrase.Split(new char[] {' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
string nth = splited.Length >= n ? splited[n-1] : "N/A";
Console.WriteLine(nth);
```

Comment: @vasily.sib Thanks I took care of it.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this was helpful!

Answer (score 2):

```
using System;
using System.Linq; // !! important

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string phrase = Console.ReadLine();
        int wordIndex = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        var result = phrase.Split(new []{' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
            .Skip(wordIndex - 1)
            .FirstOrDefault(); 
        Console.WriteLine(result ?? "N/A");
    }
}
```

output:

```
>hello, this is a test
>3
is
```

Another option, same result

```
var result = phrase.Split()
    .Where(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x))
    .Skip(wordIndex - 1)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply clean double spaces: `while (phrase.IndexOf("  ") != -1) phrase = phrase.Replace("  ", " ");`. `while` loop is necessary in case of 4+ spaces between words. The solution with `Split` and `RemoveEmptyEntries` is better, my answer is yet another solution.